# FOR loop not progressing through folder structure

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, 7zip

Should be an easy one but some reason googling and even using similar code from other projects isn't helping me get unstuck.

**AIMS:**
Batch file sat in root of USB stick to contain a one liner that recursively scans through all the folders on the drive in turn and where it finds a certain sfx file by wildcard name, update a file within it.

**PROBLEM:**
Current code works but only for the first file it finds and just repeats over and over again, never drops to the next folder where there is another file.

There are about 10 folders on the drive and 5 have a file inside which periodically will need an update, `eg_file1.exe`, `eg_file2.exe`, `eg_file3.exe`, `eg_file4.exe`, `eg_file5.exe`. I could have 5 separate lines of code but prefer to have an efficient less cluttered script.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious so anyone who can point it out or assist would be of great help.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
pushd %~dp0

for /r %%f in ("*EG_*.exe") DO ("%~dp07za.exe" u "%%~ff" "%~dp0configs\config.cfg")

pause
exit
```

Comment: Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/batch-file/3695/for-loops-in-batch-files#t=201703061006249850917

Comment: thanks this useful link, have saved for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The batch code in question searches recursively for `*EG_*.exe` and updates all files found which results in processing the same file again and again because the list of files matched by the wildcard pattern changes while processing each file matching the pattern.

The solution is using command **DIR** to first get the complete list of all files matching the wildcard pattern and in next step process this list. In this case it does not matter that the found files are updated as the list of files is already completely output by **DIR** command before **FOR** processes the files list.

```
pushd "%~dp0"
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /ON /S "*EG_*.exe"') do "%~dp07za.exe" u "%%~fI" "%~dp0configs\config.cfg"
popd
exit /B
```

This is especially important on USB sticks using a FAT file system on which the list of files matching a wildcard pattern is not sorted automatically as done by NTFS on NTFS partitions. On FAT partitions the list of files matching a wildcard pattern is returned as stored in file allocation table of the partition/drive which changes on every file/directory update. This can be seen by running a simple **DIR** on a directory on a FAT partition (FAT16, FAT32, exFAT), then modify a file in that directory and run once again **DIR**. The order of file names of second **DIR** execution is different to order of file names of first **DIR** execution although the same file names are output because no file was added or deleted in directory as just one file was modified (updated).

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. Explains why the behaviour was different when using similar in a different folder with (NTFS)